# AsyncTask argument in android

Tags: android, sendmail, android-asynctask

I am creating an app in which on clicking on button user can send email.
But I want the task of sending email should be done in Background.
Someone suggested me to use AsyncTask but I am totally unaware of this.
can anybody tell me how to do it ?
I have sendEmail function which takes two string parameters(username , password) and I don't know how to pass that two string args to AsyncTask and to doInBackground method.
my sendEmail function is

```
    public void sendEmail(String ownerEmailid, String datapwd )
{
    try {

        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender( ownerEmailid, datapwd );
        sender.sendMail( "This is Subject",   
                         "Hey buddy listen to this station it is awesome",
                         ownerEmailid,   
                         email );
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
    } 
}
```

please suggest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in onClick call

```
new SendEmail(0).execute();

/** Inner class for implementing progress bar before fetching data **/
    private class SendEmail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> 
    {
//if you want to show progress you can show here

  //  private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivityClass.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
//           Dialog.setMessage("Doing something...");
   //     Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        //Task for sending mail

try {

        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender( ownerEmailid, datapwd );
        sender.sendMail( "This is Subject",   
                         "Hey buddy listen to this station it is awesome",
                         ownerEmailid,   
                         email );
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
    } 
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {

        if(result==0)
        {
//do some thing
        }

// after completed finished the progressbar
 //       Dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: I just needed to change one small thing and it worked...instead of new SendEmail(0).execute();
I wrote new SendEmail().execute(); and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String email = params[0];
                    String name = params[1];


                        // do whatever with your strings..
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute() {

        }

    }

new YourTask().execute("tes@test.com", "Test User name");
```

First parameter of AsyncTask is your input paramater type (Your need is String), second parameter is used when process is being executed, for example you can update your progress indicator, and finally third parameter is your return parameter. If you want to show an alert or whatever according to your output, you can pass parameters to onPostExecute method by this parameters.

If you want to show an progress dialog you should override **onPreExecute** function.

Hope this helps.